# Razor page authorization not loading page when user is authenticated

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, authorization, razor-pages

I have been trying to implement basic authentication into my Razor 3.0 web app.

I have a user being signed in via *SignInAsync()*, however when trying to redirect to a page that requires Authorization, the page does not load. Instead the Login page reloads, with the  URL being updated with a "*?ReturnUrl=%Page%Path*" appended.

**Startup.cs**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
        services.AddRazorPages(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Admin");
            options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Login");
            options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Login", "");
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie();
  }

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
  {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
  }
```

Here I am setting the Admin folder to require authorization, and allowing anonymous users to access the login page.

**Login.cshtml.cs**

```
    [BindProperty]
    public UserModel UserLogin { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var loginInfo = apiConnector.Get();

                if (loginInfo)
                {
                    await this.SignInUser(UserLogin.Username, false);

                    return this.RedirectToPage("/Admin/FormOverview");
                }                    
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e);
        }      
     
        return this.Page();      
    }


    private async Task SignInUser(string username, bool isPersistant)
    {
        try
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>() {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)
            };

            var claimIdentities = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            var claimPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimIdentities);

            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                AllowRefresh = true,
                IsPersistent = true,
            };

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, claimPrincipal, authProperties);
    }
```

Here I've set up a dummy API which always returns true, with the user having a Claim created them and signing them in.

- I have tried debugging through and I can see that the User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is being set to true correctly
- when I remove Authorization from the Admin folder the page redirects correctly
- The Claim on the user is being registered after sign-in

I am new to Razor so I may be approaching this incorrectly, any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order matters

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```